# Bootstrap-UI $apply already in progress

Tags: angularjs

Unfortunately I have a new a problem with tooltip of bootstrap-UI.

On my Page I have a button with a tooltip and a function If user clicks it:

```
<button type="button" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip="On the Left!" ng-click="areYouSure()">clickIt</button>`
```

If User clicks this button the following method will be called:

```
$scope.areYouSure = function()
{
  confirm("Are you sure?")
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

But every time the user clicks the button I got following error (In the plunkr you see it in developer tools):

`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply minErr/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:78:12 beginPhase@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12720:1        $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12509:11 hideTooltipBind@http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js:2589:15 createEventHandler/eventHandler/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:2780:7 forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:330:11 createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:2779:5 $scope.areYouSure@http://run.plnkr.co/F2xBYJzoBOq7rOlg/example.js:5:5 Parser.prototype.functionCall/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:10567:15 ngEventDirectives[directiveName]</<.compile/</</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:18627:17 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12412:16 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12510:18 ngEventDirectives[directiveName]</<.compile/</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:18626:15 createEventHandler/eventHandler/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:2780:7 forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:330:11 createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:2779:5`

I think this error only appears in Firefox.

I don't understand that, can somebody help me please?

Thank you
Regards

Edit: here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xs88PpomBD8uuyNau2V7?p=preview

Comment: Try window.confirm, rather than just confirm. It fixed it for me. See my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848518/apply-already-in-progress-when-opening-confirm-dialog-box-with-firefox/35558366#35558366

Answer (score 2):

You can use $timeout to run the `confirm` dialog after the current event execution.  This prevents the error and allows the tooltip to be dismissed.

I made a [modified plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mUYDAZVhsNOyVSR4CLQL?p=preview) to show the two methods side-by-side:

```
controller('TooltipDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    // "$apply already in progress" error
    $scope.areYouSure1 = function(){
      confirm("Are you sure?");
    };

    // No error
    $scope.areYouSure2 = function(){
      $timeout(function () {
        confirm("Are you sure?");
      }, 0);
    };

  }
]);
```